# Simple IF(OR statement

Tags: excel

I normally just use excel IF statements and will nest a lot of them together just because im lazy.  But today I needed like 29 of them and was getting a character error so I decided to use

=IF(OR(A1=1, A1=2), "1", "2")

I don't normally use OR, so I  didn't think this would be a big deal, but it will either just show my code in the cell or it will be blank, I cant get it to just produce a 1 or 2 no matter what I do.  Am I simply overlooking something?  Or doing something wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the formula, aside from making numbers into strings, but you may want that.  Make sure your cells are not formatted as text.

Comment: That formula will output a 1 if A1 is 1 or 2, otherwise it will return a 2.  It would never return a "blank".  I suspect the problem is with formatting, auto-calculation, or something else.

Answer (score -3):

you must use ; and not ,

=IF(OR(A1=1; A1=2); "1"; "2")

Comment: Just to note: this may be correct, but it depends on the regional settings.

Comment: Not necessarily, My Excel I use `,` and not `;`.  It depends on your local settings.